# What were the limits of trade and exchange in the Soviet Union? What about other communist countries?

Tags: political-economy, free-trade, economic-history, communism

I'm particularly wondering about what implications the abolition of private property had for families. Since private property was to be abolished, I assume houses were not legally allowed to be traded between individuals, whether as gifts, inheritance, etc. What were the limits of this? How much giftgiving was allowed? Were gifts above a certain monetary value disallowed, or did they need to carry some "productive" essence, in the way that some will argue for a distinction between private/productive and personal property?

Comment: Welcome! Not sure that the title is in line with the content of the question. These questions are good but too broad to get a good answer. Perhaps you should consider one question at a time.

Comment: Some basic information here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_the_Soviet_Union#Forms_of_property

Comment: My understanding is that private ownership of certain consumption goods (food, clothes, etc.) was allowed but ownership of the means of production (e.g. factories) was not. Of course, this is oversimplified.